# Efficient use of Parse in swift

Tags: arrays, swift, database, parse-platform

I'm building an app and I'm using Parse database.
The app is almost finished but to be honest, I was too dumb to think about efficiency from the beginning. That's why I have this question.
Also, I have already searched for answers in the Parse Docs but couldn't find a solution.

So...

I have a list with communities, in that list I want to show the last 3 joined members from that community.  I have two tables: **User** and **Community**.

So I load the Community and check the last 3 joined members and receive the `objectId` from the last 3 users. 
Now I want to check which user profile picture matches the `objectId`.
So let's say I have a list with 4 communities --> 4comm * 3 users = 12 images to be found.

The only way I know to do this is with

```
PFUser.query()?.getObjectInBackground(withId: XXX)...
```

But then I would connect with Parse 12 times !

Is there anyway to not have to connect so many times? I already thought of a way to load the database when the app opens (in the beginning) but then the whole database would be stored in the device...

Hopefully someone can help me out, thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: Inside Community, is the list of Users an array or a relation ?

Comment: One way is to already have the recent users list in a new attribute. E.g: `recentJoinedUsers` has the list of the last X users that joined Community Y (backed by CloudCode). By doing this, you'd be able to use includeKey("recentJoinedUsers") and finally `recentUser.imageUrl`

Comment: @nathan it's an array , and I don't need a new attribute I think because I can get the objectId's from the last 3 users already. With the thing you say I will still have to connect to Parse for every community, or am I wrong?

Comment: `I will still have to connect to Parse for every community`. There's no way around it, you need to request Parse for up-to-date data so you'll need to fetch the recent memebers. By using a new attribute + includeKey you can only retrieve data for those users instead of all the members.

Comment: Oh okay thank you very much ! But eum I'm using back4app and I have like 40requests/second maximum. So if I have a lot of users using my app, they will have to wait very very long , right?

Comment: If you need that data to be updated in real time, maybe you should consider something like Redis. 40 req/s is quite a lot for a small app. If you are going to have tens of thousands of users, maybe you should reconsider your architecture (multiple instances, load balancing, etc.).